# In linux: writing into a FIFO

Tags: linux, unix, shell, fifo

I created a new FIFO using the `mkfifo` command. I have a text file `f.txt`.
I want to write the text file into my FIFO. How? Is there a unix command for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `cat`:

```
mkfifo /tmp/foo
cat f.txt > /tmp/foo
```

You'll see that it hangs, because you also need a reader process, as `cat`.

```
cat /tmp/foo
```

You can also start first the reader process and then the writer one.

Answer (score 4):

Just redirect into the pipe:

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
cat f.txt > /tmp/pipe &
cat /tmp/pipe
```

Note, this is roughly what `cat f.txt | cat` does, but this a named pipe instead of an anonymous pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Same as any file I think:

```
cat f.txt > myfifo
```

Most things can be treated like files in Linux/Unix